# When emacs connects to slime, it keeps polling, prompting that the internal error file "../src/pathname" is on line 6115

Tags: emacs, clisp, slime

[image]

My emacs version is 27.0 clisp version is 2.48 slime is 2.22.
The operating system is windows10.

[image]

Comment: Please include the error message and configuration as text, not as screenshots. You can [edit] the question, paste the text, mark it, and then click the `{}` button in the editor to format them properly as code.

Comment: Thanks, the problem has been solved, I noticed that my .emacs.d path has an exception name, so just change the path. I will pay attention to the formatting problem. Thank you very much.